# Can't find the bug in jQuery code

Tags: jquery, html

I have two buttons that are doing exactly the same thing. But one is not working and the other is.
I can't find the bug...

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('#liText').hide(0);
                $('#tableButton').click(function () {
                    $('#liText').show(2000);
                    $('#mercaz').fadeOut();
                    $('#mercaz').css({
                        'margin-top': '0'
                    });
                    $('#MainImg').css({
                        'width': '150px',
                        'height': '150px',
                        'margin-top': '5px',
                        'margin-left': '70px'
                    });
                    $('#textKoteret').css({
                        'margin-top': '30px'
                    });
                    $('#koteret').css({
                        'margin-bottom': '10px'
                    });
                    $('#mercaz').fadeIn();
                    $('.tabbable').show();
                });

                $('#tableButton2').click(function () {
                    $('#liText').show(2000);
                    $('#mercaz').fadeOut();
                    $('#mercaz').css({
                        'margin-top': '0'
                    });
                    $('#MainImg').css({
                        'width': '150px',
                        'height': '150px',
                        'margin-top': '5px',
                        'margin-left': '70px'
                    });
                    $('#textKoteret').css({
                        'margin-top': '30px'
                    });
                    $('#koteret').css({
                        'margin-bottom': '10px'
                    });
                    $('#mercaz').fadeIn();
                    $('.tabbable').show();
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

HTML button:

```
  <INPUT TYPE="button" id="#tableButton" class="btn btn-primary" VALUE="Go" onClick=<a href="#tab-711-1" data-toggle="tab"/>
  <INPUT TYPE="button" id="#tableButton2" class="btn btn-primary" VALUE="Go" onClick=<a href="#tab-711-5" data-toggle="tab"/>
```

I will be glad if someone will help me here. I am new with this.

Comment: Explain not working please.

Comment: `<INPUT TYPE="button" id="#tableButton" class="btn btn-primary" VALUE="Go" onClick=<a href="#tab-711-1" data-toggle="tab"/>` doesn't make sense. you cannot put an anchor element within an input element. that is not how html works. your jquery code looks fine

Comment: remove the **`#`** in the element's **`id`** attribute and try. Also what is with **`onClick`** ? it has some markups

Comment: also you already have a click event handler , you don't need to specify an `onclick` attribute if you have a click event handler already defined

Comment: @anurupr Hey,thanks for your answer. I remove the '#' in the element id and it's work. but how it doesn't make sense for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors I Found:
1) In HTML remove the # from id. **#selector** is used in CSS and Jquery not in simple HTML

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" id="tableButton" class="btn btn-primary" VALUE="Go" onClick=<a href="#tab-711-1" data-toggle="tab"/>
```

2) `onClick=<a href="#tab-711-1" data-toggle="tab"/>` this doesn't works in HTML. onclick event handler is used to run JS code not HTML.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. i remove #selector and it's work.

Comment: `onClick=<a href="#tab-711-1" data-toggle="tab"/>` is working and do exactly what i want...

Comment: @dmitriy Ok That's strange. I will do some research on it.